# Binding DataGrid wth ComboBox (PropertyChanged, WPF, Binding)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, datagrid

On UserControl into xmal have ComboBox filled "Id" items:

`<ComboBox x:Name="cmbId" DisplayMemberPath="Id"/>`

cs:

```
cmbId.ItemsSource = (from q in mydata.test_views
                     select q).ToList();
```

I'm trying to fill data into DataGrid:

```
 <DataGrid x:Name="UGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Auto Name" Binding="{Binding SelectedItem.AutoName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ElementName=cmbId}" Width="100"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Color" Binding="{Binding SelectedItem.Color, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ElementName=cmbId}" Width="100"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
 </DataGrid>
```

How to display data "Auto Name & Color" value after user select item on ComboBox?

Comment: Do you use any event ?
I would plug the combobox SelectedIndexChanged to a variable in the VM and bind the datagrid to it.

Comment: Are you trying to display a single item in a DataGrid?

Comment: @mm8 - yes, single value - it will be one line for selected ID, contains Auto_Name and Color value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ItemsSource` of a `DataGrid` is supposed to be set to an `IEnumerable<T>`. If you only want to display a single item in the `DataGrid`, you could handle the `SelectionChanged` event for the `ComboBox` and set the `ItemsSource` property of the `DataGrid` to a `List<T>` that contains the selected item in the `ComboBox`:

```
private void cmbId_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    UGrid.ItemsSource = new List<YourEntityType> { cmbId.SelectedItem as YourEntityType };
}
```

---

```
<DataGrid x:Name="UGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Auto Name" Binding="{Binding AutoName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="100"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Color" Binding="{Binding Color, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="100"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an event in combobox:

> ```
> > <ComboBox x:Name="cmbId" DisplayMemberPath="Id"
> > SelectionChanged="selectionInComboboxChanged"/>
> ```

And in the selectionInComboboxChanged you can get the selected cobobox item and then add it to the mydata.test_views list.